# Select dropdown form options in HTML are (when clicked) way to big relative to the initial select box?

Tags: html, css, select, dropdown

Apologies if my phrasing is weird, still relatively new to css/html. When i click the dropdown box to select the options, the options are way bigger than the select box itself, and i have no idea how to fix it. It seems to have something to do with the size of the window im viewing it in (1080x2400) because viewing in a regular window without having inspect element open doesnt bring up the issue. Thanks for the help!

[Screenshot of the weird overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsQmz.png)

HTML:

```html
<div class="addSoundScreen">
    <label for="audioType">Choose Category</label>
    <select id="audioType">
        <option value="music">Music</option>
        <option value="ambiance">Ambiance</option>
        <option value="effects">Effects</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.addSoundScreen {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.705);
    
    bottom: 20vh;
    left: 15vw;
    height: 70vh;
    width: 70vw;
    border-radius: 10%;
    
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    font-size: 280%;
    text-align: center;
    color: aliceblue;
}

.addSoundScreen select {
    margin: 1%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 5%;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

It got larger when I tried to increase the font size, but even when I adjust the font size of the "options" it doesnt remove all that extra room that overflows out of the window (see screenshot).

Comment: Please could you make your code into a runnable snippet. In particular, what is addSoundScreen?

Comment: addsoundscreen is a class for the parent div of the select box. I have now done my best to turn it into a runnable snippet, but to fully replicate the page would be a lot of code

Comment: Have you tried setting the position of the "select" css to fixed?

Comment: I did try that, but that moves the select box to to the top of the div, which only exacerbates the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML and CSS is correct but note that some browsers have their own way of handling selects.

**Heres an option**:

```css
.addSoundScreen select option {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

You could also try using a CSS reset to override any default styles that the browser may be applying to the select box and options.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```